# Meteor multi tenant capabilities

Tags: meteor

Is Meteor capable of remaining performant, while serving multiple distinct users?

For instance, if I declare the following publication that allows users to retrieve their own documents only:

```
Meteor.publish("UserList", function () {
  return Documents.find({user: this.userId});
});
```

And imagine thousands of users are feeding from this publication, each one for their own documents. What happens when one document gets updated? I.e., are all the users notified that their list *might* have changed? Does the server perform the query for all possible users and notifies only those that matter? How does Meteor maintain performance in such a scenario?

Or is there a better way to implement multi-tenancy in Meteor?

Answer (score 1):

In that case only the user who is subscribed to that publish function will get the update.

Meteor will send down any changes to a collection to that particular subscription. The subscriber isn't told that a document might have changed they're simply sent the change in data. DDP has a sort of 'crud' that tells the client what to do, i.e remove,update,insert..

In the case of your `Documents.find` above, that particular user will only be sent their updates and the other users won't be notified at all.

Im not 100% sure about this part because there were some changes in 0.5.7, but for every connection via DDP there would be a subscription each has its own query (even when the queries are the same to other subscriptions). It looks like the caching of this is targetted very soon on trello : https://trello.com/card/improve-server-side-performance-of-subscriptions/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/10

DDP is still in a pre1 release but I'd imagine this would be optimized further down the road, particularly on queries which aren't likely to be unique on each subscription (i.e `Documents.find()` instead of `Document.find({user:this.userId})`.)

For full specs on the DDP protocol have a look at : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md